# Change structure of an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects with unknown depth. By depth i mean that i don't know does every child have children. I'm sorry i can't find proper words to explain it closer. This is example:

```
let array =  [
    {id: 1},
    {id: 2, parentId: 1},
    {id: 3, parentId: 2},
    {id: 4, parentId: 3},
    {id: 5, parentId: 2},
    {id: 6, parentId: 1},
   ...
    {id: 100, parentId: 90}
    ]
```

Is it possible to write function in javascript that will nest objects in order matching parent id?

```
[{id: 1, children: [{id: 2, ,children: [ {id: 3}]}] ,{ id: 6} ]} ] ...
```

What is the best practice to nest object to use it later to render data and not to ask in every layer if(children)?

Comment: Yes it is. What have you tried? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

Here is a method that creates a map to track which position in the array each item is. Then, the array is iterated through and added to the `children` array of the appropriate parent.

```js
const arr = [
  {id: 1},
  {id: 2, parentId: 1},
  {id: 3, parentId: 2},
  {id: 4, parentId: 3},
  {id: 5, parentId: 2},
  {id: 6, parentId: 1},
]

let map = {};

arr.forEach((el, i) => {
  map[el.id] = i;
  el.children = [];
});

let root = [];

arr.forEach(el => {
  if (!el.parentId) {
    root.push(el);
  } else {
    arr[map[el.parentId]].children.push(el);
  }
});

console.log(root);
```

Comment: Hi Nick! This is not deep, only works for a 1 level children

Comment: It sure does work for deep levels! Did you try running the code?

Comment: Some of us pre-supposed a solution required nested or recursive looping so this didn't look right. A delightful lesson on thinking in terms of keys,  "mapping" parent-to-child keys and then bam! iteration not required - just lookup.   Also a good example of how better variable names would significantly illuminate the code - `parentChildKeyMap` vice `map`. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Take an object for keeping the reference to the children.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2, parentId: 1 }, { id: 3, parentId: 2 }, { id: 4, parentId: 3 }, { id: 5, parentId: 2 }, { id: 6, parentId: 1 }],
    tree = function (data, root) {
        var o = {};
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            if (o[a.id] && o[a.id].children) {
                a.children = o[a.id].children;
            }
            o[a.id] = a;
            o[a.parentId] = o[a.parentId] || {};
            o[a.parentId].children = o[a.parentId].children || [];
            o[a.parentId].children.push(a);
        });
        return o[root].children;
    }(data, undefined);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I weep for those who inherit your code. While the code works, it makes a lot of assumptions with no explanation.

Comment: Namely: unless you had the dataset right in front of you, it would probably take a *long* time to figure out that `o[a.parentId]` maps to `o[undefined]` for your root node. This also does not consider the possibility of there being multiple top-level nodes. Considering the desired output is an array, it may indicate that there may be multiple top-level elements and not a single tree structure as the example data might suggest.

Comment: @mhodges, some of the assumption: not sorted data, root level can have morte than one node, single loop, without previously collected parent children relations, missing `parentId` (`undefined`) as single root node, otherwise op has specified this problem. but you are right, without a view to data theis code has just two assingments inside, basically an assignment to `o[a.id]`, which is an access to the object with the given `id` and the same for the parent node `o[a.parentId]`. nothing more, just simple.

Comment: the result is a double linked tree structure, where you could take any `id` or `parentId` and get the node. the returned result is just pulling out the root node, where all other nodes are connected to.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [
  {id: 1},
  {id: 2, parentId: 1},
  {id: 3, parentId: 2},
  {id: 4, parentId: 3},
  {id: 5, parentId: 2},
  {id: 6, parentId: 1},
];

const findParent = (list, parentId) => {
  list = list || [];
  return list.find(el => el.id === parentId);
}

const findDeepParent = (list, parentId) => {
   for(const i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      const element = list[i];
      const parent = findParent(list, parentId);
      if (parent) { 
        return parent 
      } else if(element.children) {
        return findDeepParent(element.children, parentId);
      };
   }
}

const objs = array.reduce((result, obj) => {
  let found = false;
  if (obj.parentId) {
    var parent = findDeepParent(result, obj.parentId)
    if (parent) {
      parent.children = parent.children || [];
      parent.children.push(obj);
      found = true;
    }
  } 
  if(!found) {
    result.push(obj);
  }
  
  return result;
}, []);

console.log(objs);
```

**This solve your problem**